# What is the meaning of the com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.ViewStackPolicy values?

Tags: javadoc, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am looking at the Gluon mobile code generated by the Gluon plugin and I cannot find the description of the com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.ViewStackPolicy values in the javadoc.

I looked at:
https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/

```
final Item primaryItem = new ViewItem("Primary", MaterialDesignIcon.HOME.graphic(), PRIMARY_VIEW, ViewStackPolicy.SKIP);
```

It would be nice to have description of the ViewStackPolicy values in the javadoc explaining what the values mean, what the impact is on the view and difference between them. Now there is no description.

Answer (score 1):

I thought you did not find the exact link I sent earlier, I am sorry I was not helpful, hopefully this edited post is clearer. ViewStackPolicy is basically a stack that keeps track of the screens you viewed. So a stack is a LIFO (last in, first out). imagine having 2 view: view1 and view2 so the Enumeration literal USE: if you add USE to view1, it add view1 to that stack. then if you switch your view to view2 and you can click on the Android back button and it will go back to the view1. (as it was the last to enter the stack, so its the first to leave the stack) as for SKIP: it skips adding the view to the stack, so if you go to view2 and you click on the back button it will go back the view before view1 (if there is one) lastly CLEAR: it clears your stack I hope this was more helpful, sorry about the earlier post.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes sense now.